# Rails: send_file never renders page or DoubleRender error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file

So I'm trying to trigger a download after the user completes a purchase on my page. I am using `send_file` which works but my checkout page never gets rendered after the file is send.  If I try to explicitly render the result page I get an DoubleRender error.

So I'm lost on what the correct things to do is: I have a page called getapk.erb and have the getfile code in it's controller.

How can I render both the page and send the file to the user?

Answer (score 5):

When you 'send_file' that is a render in it's self. So displaying a 'success' page and sending a file is two separate renders.

I would make the success page and file download two separate controller actions, and display a link to the file download on the success page.

e.g.

```
def success
 #show html page with file download link
end

def file_download
 send_file #make sure you have :inline => false
end
```

Then you could use javascript to make it appear they are rendering both at the same time.

At the bottom of your success.erb put somthing like this to bring up the download dialog box automatically on render of the success page.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    window.location=<%=url_for :action=>"file_download", :id => 'etc' %>;

</script>
```