# What happend after send_file in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the `index` view, there is a link to download file:

```
<%= link_to filename, listing_download_path(:file => filename) %>
```

In the controller:

```
def download
    pathname = File.join(USER_FOLDER, params[:file])
    if File.file?(pathname)
      send_file pathname
    end
  end
end
```

When the user click download, a file download popup is shown. What's happen after the file is downloaded? Does rails just sit there and do nothing more? If I delete the `send_file` line, `dwonload.html.erb` will be rendered. Does `send_file` skip view rendering?

What if I want to show soemthing like "You have downloaded ..."?

Comment: I think rails(or ruby) does not go about sending data itself. It uses X-Sendfile to hand over the data processing/sending to the web server. You can read about it here: http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `send_file` is a render itself. You could use the approach proposed in this question:

[Rails: send_file never renders page or DoubleRender error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000561/rails-send-file-never-renders-page-or-doublerender-error)

Basically your download link will send to a "success" view, from which you call the download file method automatically.